# How to create a nested stencil with rappid?

Tags: rappid

my application is based on the kitchensink demo. I would like to create a nested stencil but I can't figure out how to do it. Is this possible - any help?

Regards
Dieter

Comment: you can override stencil render method to render group inside another group

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure about what you mean as "a nested stencil".)

there are basically two options to do "multi level accordion" for shapes in stencil:

1. create accordion on your own and use many stencil instances
2. use actual stencil and override `renderGroup` method to render group in group

   - group will have as content paper with its own shapes + group (before or after)

please let me know if I understood well and where exactly you are stucked

Comment: I think multi level accordion is the correct term; I will try like you suggested.